# Removing SBT projects and removing Typesafe Stack

Tags: scala, sbt, typesafe-stack

I recently discovered the Typesafe Stack (and through it, SBT and g8) - loving it. However, when I first started I was messing around a lot after it installed, and I kind of want to do a clean install of the Typesafe stack. Do I just need to delete the entire `typesafe-stack` folder, or are there other hidden folders/files as well?

Also, for SBT projects, same question - do I just need to `rm -r` the project folder or are there other files?

Thanks!
-kstruct

Comment: SBT leaves a lot of stuff in `~/.sbt` and `~/.ivy2`. Don't know about the rest of the Typesafe Stack.

Comment: If I do not have Scala on a machine, and I install SBT and compile, it says something like "installing scala" in the process - does this actually install Scala on the system or just something local to that project?

Comment: I guess a better question actually is this: I had Scala 2.9.1 on my local machine. I then installed the Typesafe Stack, which (to my understand) is basically `sbt` and `g8`. I ran `g8` and `sbt` which installed some stuff, and I'm guessing since 2.9.1 was already on my machine, `sbt` didn't install 2.9.1. My question now is, what should `sbt`'s behavior be?

Comment: OK so it seems it installs Scala to `~/.sbt/boot/`.. is this true? If so, how do I get `scala` and `scalac` to get called just by typing it?

Comment: It grabs scala compiler and scala library jar files so sbt can internally use it, but sbt won't make `scala` or `scalac` command available from your shell. For that you could download scala manually from http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads. Further questions should be asked as separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sbt uses Ivy to cache dependent libraries under `~/.ivy2/`. sbt itself is cached under `~/.sbt/`.
Since giter8 is a conscript application, the jar of giter8 is cached under `~/.conscript/`.
The script `g8` is created under ~/bin/.

Don't know much about the typesafe stack.